# How can I get every object belonging to a hierarchy of classes that include certain attribute?

Tags: scala, reflection, class-hierarchy

Let's suppose I have a hierarchy like this:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
trait Animal {
    def name: String
}

trait Reptile extends Animal

trait Bird extends Animal

trait Mammal extends Animal

case class Snake(name: String) extends Reptile

case class Parrot(name: String, beak: String, wings: String) extends Bird

case class Platypus(name: String, beak: String, fur: String) extends Mammal

case class Cat(name: String, fur: String) extends Mammal
```

Question is: **How can I get every animal in a list of animals that has a certain attribute?**
For example, I might want to get every instance of animal with fur in my list. I think I could use reflection to iterate over the hierarchy of classes but I want to avoid that. Another possibility would be to add a trait "AnimalWithFur" and then every animal with fur would have to extend it. If I have a **Seq[Animal] animals**, I could do something like this:

```
val animalsWithFur:Seq[AnimalWithFur] = animals.collect{case a: AnimalWithFur => a}
```

but I'd need a new trait for every new characteristic in any animal class (fins, paws, etc.).

This model should escalate, therefore I might add many new animals and features in the future.
I also need to keep this hierarchy because I might want to list every Mammal or every Bird. Also I can't simply add "beak" as a feature of birds because platypuses also have beaks.

Comment: If you want it to be verified at compile time, I think you would have to create the `AnimalWithFur` trait. If not, you could just define a boolean `hasFur` in `Animal` which the concrete animals would have to implement. Using reflection for such a simple task is a big no in my book.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to create `trait AnimalWithFur` but if you have some general information about animals (so a lot of animals have fur) or only fields that you want to filter you can add e.g. method `hasFur` with default return value `false` and override it in places when you need to have a `true` and filter collection or add it's as option field and the same solution.

Example:

```
trait Animal {
  val hasFur: Boolean = false

  def name: String
}
```

But in this case every animal will have this field, so I don't know that this solution is good for you.